# Assembly program gives me segfault

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm

I'm trying to write a compiler but I am not very good at it. It compiles / assembles without any errors but it gives me segfault at runtime.

Here is how I assemble my assembly source code (on ubuntu linux) :

```
nasm -f elf64 assembly.asm
ld -s -o assembly assembly.o --entry entrypoint
./assembly ; echo $?
```

Here is my assembly source code:

```
global entrypoint
entrypoint:
    call main 
main:
    mov eax, 0
    ret
```

Here is what it gives to me :

```
Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./assembly
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the `ret` returns after `call main`, control ends up at the instruction after the `call`, which happens to be the beginning of `main` again. After the `mov` instruction runs a second time, next is `ret` again, but now there's no corresponding `call`, causing the instruction pointer to be pointing to whatever bytes just happened to be next on the stack. This is almost certainly not going to be executable memory, so a segfault occurs when it tries to execute there.

Comment: In the x86-64 System V ABI, `rsp` on process entry (`_start:`) points at `argc` (a small integer, not a valid return address).  Unlike Windows, there's no return address anywhere that you can use, you need to make an `_exit` or `exit_group` system call.